# Flexicious Components Style Options

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flexicious

Is there a reference somewhere that lists all the style options for each type of component?

Comment: have you looked at http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Documentation ?

Comment: yes but I didn't see anything about style tags specific to those components

Comment: If they don't provide one; I assume you'll have to review their source code, if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Documentation Each component has a "styles" section that should get you what you want. Also, look at the inheritance hierarchy of the control you are interested in, many styles are inherited and you can look at the base class styles also.

For example, styles for our Ultimate datagrid are here: (search for styles)

http://www.flexicious.com/resources/docs29/com/flexicious/nestedtreedatagrid/FlexDataGrid.html